# Trying to validate a json against Json Schema in java but getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, json, nosuchmethoderror, json-schema-validator

I want to validate a JSON object with JSON schema.

This is my method:

```
public static void jsonSchemValidator(String json, String defination) throws ValidationException, JSONException, IOException )
{

    JSONObject jsonSchemaori = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(readFromResources(defination)));
    JSONObject jsonSubject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(readFromResources(json)));

    Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchemaori);
    schema.validate(jsonSubject);
}

String defination="src/test/resources/json/pick_event_schema.json";
String json="src/test/resources/json/pickevent1.json";
Utils.jsonSchemValidator(json,schema);
```

I generated the Schema file from the following site: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter

This is my readFromResources:

```
public static String readFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(fileName);
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr) ) {
            String contentLine = br.readLine();
            while (contentLine != null) {
                sb.append(contentLine);
                contentLine = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.getNames(Lorg/json/JSONObject;)[Ljava/lang/String;
```

Please let me where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: This usually means the version of the library that you used during compilation is newer than the library in your deployed environment.  The compiler found the method but at runtime that method does not exist.  Check your library versions.

Comment: @JimGarrison can you please tell me which library to look for?